# How can I schedule processes/tasks in ruby (on rails) when timing is important?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

I'm writing an app in Ruby on Rails and have a question regarding tasks/processes that I want executed at certain points in time.

At the moment I'm using Redis and [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq).
This works great as Sidekiq supports scheduled jobs since version 2.0. 
They look like this

```
SomeWorker.perform_in(5.days, 'bob', 13)
SomeWorker.perform_at(5.days.from_now, 'bob', 13)
```

[more info](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md#200)

However, timing is very important for my app and Sidekiq does not seem to particularly care about it.
By default scheduled jobs are polled every 15 seconds:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.poll_interval = 15
end
```

this can be changed to, let's say, 1 second, but this is not advised by Sidekiq:

> WARNING: If you have dozens or hundreds of Sidekiq processes, you should raise the poll_interval significantly. process_count * 5 is a reasonable poll_interval for most. Otherwise your processes will slam Redis constantly looking for new scheduled jobs to run.

What would be the best option that allows me have multiple processes per second (the processes are small), executed as closely to the set execution time as possible (no more than a 1 second difference)?

Comment: And how many Sidekiq processes are you expecting?

Comment: @D-side I'm not expecting many as this is a fun/learning side project for me. But I want it to be able to handle around 10-20 processes a second.

Answer (score 0):

Please use process and job correctly so we are communicating precisely.  A Sidekiq process has many threads, each thread processes one job at a time.

If you have 3 Sidekiq processes and set your poll_interval to 3, on average the scheduled set of jobs will be checked once per second.  Do the math as necessary for your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

you can use whenever gem and you can set time in Schedule.rb for tasks and you need to use crontab you set the environment and for crontab google it for more details

Comment: In `cron` the minimum timeframe is often 30-60 seconds. Quite a lot.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more?  Great answers include an example.

Comment: Also, usually in English we use periods to separate different thoughts.  Using too many "and"s makes your post hard to understand.

Comment: you can visit whenever gem repository on github it will explain what i was trying to say